# What's the state of Mono (& Monodevelop) on Linux (specially on Ubuntu)?

Tags: gtk3, mono, monodevelop

recently I've starting developing using Xamarin Studio on Windows (using GTK#), but I want to ensure portability to Mac OS X and Linux distros, specially Debian and Ubuntu.

I've seen that Mono on Windows it's outdated (version 3.2.8, while the current last "stable" version is the 3.8), and in Ubuntu we have a similar situation. In the next release (14.10, Utopic Unicorn) the mono packages are still in the 3.2.8 version...

Anyone knows why? License problems? New intellectual property risks? The 3.4 version was released on March of this year. I could understand that the 3.6 or 3.8 versions are considered "too recent" (too few testing time...), but we still have the 3.4 version, which is pretty "old" (they had a complete release cycle to include it).

And we have the problem with GTK#3 too, I couldn't find a roadmap with date approximations...

I'll be grateful for any information about the state of things on this technology stack. Thanks in advance! :) .

Comment: I don't have enough information to write a full answer but I know xamarin just hired a guy to update all this stuff.